# NSAppTransportSecurity & Facebook

Tags: ios9, xcode7, nsapptransportsecurity

Under iOS 9 my UIWebview loading company's Facebook page is working only with the  NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key set to YES, otherwhise results the following error :

NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

any sugestions ?

Answer (score 4):

Open your Info.plist file as source code and make sure "NSAppTransportSecurity" key looks like this (more info on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time, by the way it worked  for both twitter and youtube